# Covering of genus 2 of elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I am reading this paper and I get confused somewhere:

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-0457-2_7

So the set up is the following:

Let $C$ be a genus 2 curve. Suppose $C$ admits a degree $n$ covering of elliptic curve $E_{1}$ over a field $K$:
$$\phi_{1}: C \to E_{1}$$
where $n$ prime to char $K$. Assume there is no non tirivial unramified covering between $E_{1}$ and $C$. Let $J$ be the jacobian of $C$. Then there are induced maps by $\phi_{1}$:
$$\phi_{1}^{*}:E_{1} \to J$$
$$\phi_{1,*}:J \to E_{1}$$
(The authors didn't say how these maps work explicitly, my understanding of these two maps are: $\phi_{1}^{*}$ is the pullback from $E_{1}$ to $C^{n}$ and then map to $J$; $\phi_{1,*}$ maps $J$ to $C^{n}$ then each factor of $C^{n}$ maps to $E_{1}$ and add up in $E_{1}$.)

The author said that the maximality of $C \to E_{1}$ implies that $\phi_{1}$ is injective and that $ker(\phi_{1,*})$ is an elliptic curve $E_{2}^{*}$ (cf. Serre). **Why this $\phi_{1}$ is injective? Isn't it a degree $n$ covering so one should expect $n$ preimages generically?**

The projection map $\phi_{2,*}: J \to J/E_{1}^{*}=:E_{2}$ induces a covering
$$\phi_{2}:C \to E_{2}$$ 
of degree $n$. And the map 
$$h:\phi_{1}^{*} \times \phi_{2}^{*}:E_{1} \times E_{2} \to J$$
is an isogeny of degree $n^{2}$. **Why it is of degree $n^{2}$? I've tried the sum of pullbacks but it looks not easy to find (explitcitly) the $n^{2}$ kernel. Anyone knows how this map works on elements?**

I very appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you sure they say $\phi_1$ is injective? It should be $\phi_1^*$.

Comment: I am confused by this too. You can click the link it is in the preview second page bottom.

Comment: It is a typo, I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, about the induced maps by $\phi_{1}$:
$$\phi_{1}^{*}:E_{1} \to J$$
$$\phi_{1,*}:J \to E_{1}$$
the correspond, $\phi_1^*$ to universal property of the jacobian: to a map $f:C\to C'$ of curves one gets a map $f^*:J(C')\to J(C)$ of the jacobians. If you identify the points of $J(C)$ with the degree 0 divisors $\text{Div}^0(C)$, then the map sends a point $P$ to the preimatge divisor $f^*(P)=\sum_{f(Q)=P} Q$ (with the multiplicities) and extend it by linearity. The map $\phi_{1,*}$ is the dual map ${\phi_1^*}^{\vee}$, identifying $J(C)^{\vee}$ with $J(C)$ via the principal polarization; it coincides also with the universal map for the Albanese property (so $J(C)$ is also the Albanese variety of $C$).

That $\phi_1$ is injective is clearly a typo: they meant $\phi_1^*$.

Now, to show that $h$ is a degree $n^2$ isogeny you can try the following: first, we compute the composition $$\phi_{1,*}\circ \phi_{1}^{*}: E_1\to E_1$$ as follows: given any point $P\in E_1(K)$ (say $K$ a field), $\phi_1^*(P)=\phi_1^{-1}(P)-\phi_1^{-1}(O)$ (being $O$ the zero point of $E_1$), and then 
$$\phi_{1,*}(\phi_1^*(P))=\sum_{\phi_1(Q)=P}\phi_1(Q) - \sum_{\phi_1(Q)=O}\phi_1(Q)=nP$$
(I have been a bit sloppy identifying the points $P$ in $E$ and the degree 0 divisors $P-O$ in $E$). SO we get the $$\phi_{1,*}\circ \phi_{1}^{*}=[n]_{E_1}$$ is the multiplication by $n$ in $E_1$. Same argument applies to $\phi_2$, and so we get that 
$$h^{\vee}\circ h: E_1\times E_2\to E_1\times E_2$$
is multiplication by $n$ in $E_1\times E_2$ (as $h^{\vee}=\phi_{1,*}\times\phi_{2,*}$). This shows $h$ is a degree $n^2$ isogeny.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit further why $h^{\vee} \circ h=[n]$ implies $h$ is of degree $n^{2}$?

Comment: @ZhengXiao The degree of an isogeny and its dual is the same. The degree of the composition is the product. But the degree of "multiplication by n" in an abelian surface is $n^4$, so the degree of $h$ and $h^\vee$ is $n^2$.